# AsyncController missing in MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to use the id parameter with an async iactionresult method, but it is coming through as null.

If I inherit from Controller and use -

```
public IActionResult Index(string id)
```

there is no problem. But when I use ->

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string id)
```

(which is what I need) the id parameter is always null. I am trying to inherit from the AsyncController to do this, however I am having trouble locating it using:

```
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta1"
```

Does anyone know any work around for this? Thanks!

Comment: The binding of the `id` parameter should not be dependent on whether your are returning a task or not...can you share how your routes look like and also how does your request url look like?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no `AsyncController` base class in MVC 6 in ASP.NET vNext. All controllers in MVC 6 (and MVC 4 and 5, for that matter) are async.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication49.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string id)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            return Content("I found ID: " + id);
        }
    }
}
```

And navigated to:

```
http://localhost:49479/test/index/123
```

And correctly got this result:

```
I found ID: 123
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. This worked. I had another issue which was causing the problem.

Comment: Any document state all controller in mvc 4,5,6 are async?